# ERROR while connecting to datastax linux odbc driver

Tags: cassandra, odbc, datastax

I wanted to install datastax linux odbc driver, but I m getting the error [Datastax] [ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function

Kindly resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [faq from Simba](http://www.simba.com/resources/drivers/faq/) (assuming this is the DataStax ODBC driver developed by Simba?):

> I get the following error: [Simba] [ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function
>
> This is due to not setting the ODBCInstLib in the .simba._driverName_odbc.ini correctly. Please refer to the .ini file and uncomment the correct ODBCInstLib line as indicated by the comments to match the driver manager that you are using.

Can you check for such a file in your home directory?  It should be named `.simba.cassandraodbc.ini` I am thinking, although maybe it is named something different in the DataStax version.  [Page 18 of this reference](http://www.simba.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Simba-ODBC-Driver-for-Cassandra-Install-Guide.pdf) may be helpful for configuring this file to point to the .so file.

Comment: I am using Datastax driver, in the folliowing file 
 "datastax.cassandraodbc.ini" mentioned the lib file name , 
 #   iODBC
ODBCInstLib=libiodbcinst.so

Should I use full path

Comment: I think that should work as is, if libiodbcinst.so is in directory specified in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Do you see it in /usr/lib/, /usr/local/lib or anywhere else?